# Increasing PHP memory_limit. At what point does it become insane?

Tags: php, memory, scalability

In a system I am currently working on, there is one process that loads large amount of data into an array for sorting/aggregating/whatever. I know this process needs optimising for memory usage, but in the short term it just needs to work.

Given the amount of data loaded into the array, we keep hitting the memory limit. It has been increased several times, and I am wondering is there a point where increasing it becomes generally a bad idea? or is it **only** a matter of how much RAM the machine has?

The machine has 2GB of RAM and the memory_limit is currently set at 1.5GB. We can easily add more RAM to the machine (and will anyway).

Have others encountered this kind of issue? and what were the solutions?

Comment: Honestly you should not be concerned with setting a memory limit, but with figuring out where your memory leak is and fixing it.  It is not a solution to just increase the memory_limit, it is avoiding a problem in the code. Look at which objects you are setting and unsetting values to clear up a leak.

Comment: Can you be specific about the amount of data? What do you mean by large?

Comment: @Frederico: OP is not trying to fix a memory leak, he's asking for a solution for handling very large datasets in PHP.

Comment: @Frederico I am aware this is not an ideal answer, but am looking for advice until we have a chance to Do It Better.

@Jergason It's tabular data from a database query, ~500k rows, 15 columns. Large is relative to the available memory, but it's enough to hit the memory limit at the current 1.5GB. Not sure of the final size, hence the question "when is it too much?"

Comment: Can you give us information about the task that script executes? May be we will help you optimizing the algo to eliminate excessive memory consumption.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The configuration for the `memory_limit` of PHP running as an Apache module to server webpages has to take into consideration how many Apache process you can have at the same time on the machine -- see the `MaxClients` configuration option for Apache.

If `MaxClients` is 100 and you have 2,000 MB of RAM, a very quick calculation will show that you should not use more than 20 MB *(because 20 MB * 100 clients = 2 GB or RAM, ie the total amount of memory your server has)* for the memory_limit value.

And this is without considering that there are probably other things running on the same server, like MySQL, the system itself, ... And that Apache is probably already using some memory for itself.

Or course, this is also a "worst case scenario", that considers that each PHP page is using the maximum amount of memory it can.

In your case, if you need such a big amount of memory for only one job, I would not increase the `memory_limit` for PḦP running as an Apache module.

Instead, I would launch that job from command-line *(or via a cron job)*, and specify a higher `memory_limit` specificaly in this one and only case.

This can be done with the `-d` option of php, like :

```
$ php -d memory_limit=1GB temp.php
string(3) "1GB"
```

Considering, in this case, that temp.php only contains :

```
var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));
```

In my opinion, this is way safer than increasing the memory_limit for the PHP module for Apache -- and it's what I usually do when I have a large dataset, or some really heavy stuff I cannot optimize or paginate.

If you need to define several values for the PHP CLI execution, you can also tell it to use another configuration file, instead of the default php.ini, with the `-c` option :

```
php -c /etc/phpcli.ini temp.php
```

That way, you have :

- `/etc/php.ini` for Apache, with low `memory_limit`, low `max_execution_time`, ...
- and `/etc/phpcli.ini` for batches run from command-line, with virtually no limit

This ensures your batches will be able to run -- and you'll still have security for your website (`memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` being security measures)

Still, if you have the time to optimize your script, you should ; for instance, in that kind of situation where you have to deal with lots of data, pagination is a must-have ;-)

Comment: Yes, the limit is only being upped for the process that requires it. Unfortunately though, pagination won't help in this case; the end result is only a handful (20 or so) statistical numbers, it's just the processing that requires the space.

Comment: Oh, OK... Then, I suppose it kind of depends on how much "free" memory you have when launching that process : if you launch it in the middle of the night, when there's almost no-one using your server, maybe 1.5 GB might be OK (I would use more, to let some memory to the rest of the system) -- but only you can say how much your server is loaded at that time.

Comment: in some PHP versions (e.g. PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch) the setting is 1G, not 1GB. Test it or PHP will set the limit to the lowest value and your script will fail to execute, e.g. use `php -d memory_limit=1G -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"`

Comment: I can't find `MaxClients` in my Apache2 config on Ubuntu 14.04. What does Apache do by default without this option?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried splitting the dataset into smaller parts and process only one part at the time?

If you fetch the data from a disk file, you can use the [`fread()`](https://www.php.net/fread) function to load smaller chunks, or some [sort of unbuffered db query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php) in case of database.

I haven't checked up PHP since v3.something, but you also could use a form of cloud computing. 1GB dataset seems to be big enough to be processed on multiple machines.

Comment: The plan is to only read the data as required (as you're suggesting with fread()), but that's the refactoring we haven't got to yet.

Comment: This is the actual correct answer, IMNSHO: unless the dataset is fully correlated, it is usually possible to process one part at a time, and rarely it is necessary to keep all of it in memory. As the OP notes, this often requires nontrivial refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know that there are memory issues with your script that need fixing and you are only looking for short-term solutions, then I won't address the ways to [go about profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and solving your memory issues.  It sounds like you're going to get to that.

So, I would say the main things you have to keep in mind are:

- Total memory load on the system
- OS capabilities

PHP is only one small component of the system.  If you allow it to eat up a vast quantity of your RAM, then the other processes will suffer, which could in turn affect the script itself.  Notably, if you are pulling a lot of data out of a database, then your DBMS might be require a lot of memory in order to create result sets for your queries.  As a quick fix, you might want to identify any queries you are running and free the results as soon as possible to give yourself more memory for a long job run.

In terms of OS capabilities, you should keep in mind that 32-bit systems, which you are likely running on, can only address up to 4GB of RAM without special handling.  Often the limit can be much less depending on how it's used.  Some Windows chipsets and configurations can actually have less than 3GB available to the system, even with 4GB or more physically installed.  You should check to see how much your system can address.

You say that you've increased the memory limit several times, so obviously this job is growing larger and larger in scope.  If you're up to 1.5Gb, then even installing 2Gb more RAM sounds like it will just be a short reprieve.

> Have others encountered this kind of
>   issue? and what were the solutions?

I think you probably already know that the only real solution is to break down and spend the time to optimize the script soon, or you'll end up with a job that will be too big to run.

Comment: The machine is pretty much dedicated to PHP, database servers are separate. The previous limit increases weren't because the job is increasing (though it will, but not that quickly), they were insufficient to "fix" the issue (so we tried a larger limit). We now have a limit that lets the process run, but it is definitely only a short term solution. Good point about the system limitations, it is a 64bit machine and we will be increasing the RAM anyway. Anyway, I think you've allayed my fears that throwing that much memory at a single process was absurd. RDBMS's do it, why can't I :)