# PHP f-n file_get_contents stops execution for huge html page

Tags: php, html, buffer, exit

I'm using file_get_contents function to get and parse the html, from huge page (32 000 rows).
It works for small/normal pages but with this one it just stops.

It doesn't give any error. It doesn't read the next line in my PHP script, but just stops..I tried to increase the time out time or using cURL but it still does not work.

It works on my local XAMPP but it does not work when I upload it to my hosting.
Does anyone know what setting is messed up in my PHP hosting? I think it is some buffer issue..

Comment: Do you have a console? Then try to get the page with wget http://www.. to check if it is readable.

Comment: seem to me like a usual apache-timeout. you have to configure the vhost settings, but I guess that is out of question. usually that is really the only option.

Comment: Check your apache error logs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that it is caused by [memory_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425138/increasing-php-memory-limit-at-what-point-does-it-become-insane/1425182#1425182) is some additional information regarding the directive

To determine the cause of this you should prepend code such as the following to your script (leave out log statements if you wish to display errors in the browser instead)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```