# DataTable unable to handle large data?

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

As title, I had pluged in [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) but somehow when I tried to load a database that has 100k row it fails to load. Was it the plugin problem or any recommendation on handle this big data in table?

Comment: This is a similar question please check it once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013541/jquery-datatables-large-datasource-locking-the-browser-on-init

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your php configuration.

`Memory limit` and `maximum execution time` in php.ini should be enough to get such large number of records.

And look at [Increasing PHP memory_limit. At what point does it become insane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425138/increasing-php-memory-limit-at-what-point-does-it-become-insane)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by failed? Are you creating the table in PHP, outputting it, and then calling DataTable? Are you filling the table via an AJAX call?

I would install Firebug if you are on Firefox, or use the built-in tools in Chrome or Safari. They will tell you if the JS is encountering an error, or let you inspect the responses from AJAX requests.

Comment: I had this with smaller row data like few hundreds it works like a charm but not with 100k row where chrome ask to kill page.