# JQuery Datatables Large Datasource locking the browser on init

Tags: jquery, initialization, datatables

I have a large amount of data I wish to use with Jquery [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/) Plugin (6000 rows)

I'm currently using php to return a DOM Table and styling that using

```
$("#datatable-container").children("table:first").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sScrollX": "100%"
});
```

My issue is when rendering the table my browser locks for a period of time. I understand the threading limitations of javascript... I'm wondering if there is a better way to load the data / render the table that will not lock the browser?

**Note** simple 'paging' the data will not work unless someone can inform me as to how I would go about that and not loose datatables' paging or searching features.

Comment: What 'threading limitations of Javascript' are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: There is no multi-threading.. pretty big limitation if you ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [DataTables server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) from their website I was able to correct my problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered paging your data? I think that from both a performance perspective  and a design perspective paging your data would be the choice to implement considering that your data has 6,000 rows (and how many columns:)

Page!

Another option would be to implement paging combined with local storage, if appropriate.

Comment: I don't want to loose the functionality of the DataTable (internal paging and searching)