# Unexpected token and memory limit

Tags: php, jquery, syntax-error

On my Wordpress site I'm getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` when attempting to login.

Using a plugin with an AJAX login and the issue is very strange.

When I increase the memory limit to `128MB` (or `64` or `96`) the issue disappears and there's no error.

While this might seem like a 'fix', I still don't like knowing there's something 'wrong' that should be fixed.

The problem is that I can't find what the error is, what's the best way to debug something like that and find out exactly what script or plugin or coding error is causing the SyntaxError?

And why would it only happen with a lower memory limit?

Comment: The `SyntaxError` should include a file and a line number that will help you find and debug it (if you include relevant code around this line I can help as well).  Also, WordPress tries to use `40MB` of memory by default..and many PHP configs start with a memory limit of `64MB`.  Even setting it to `128MB` isn't ridiculous..

Comment: SyntaxError is just a alert function that pops up, I checked console and I can't see any mention of it in there. It also doesn't include in the alert dialogue any mention of the file that's throwing the error.

Comment: Interesting, sounds like something custom thrown by the AJAX login plugin you have..I would try a couple Google searches with `wordpress <plugin name> syntaxerror`?

Comment: The thing that's really confusing me is why is this happening when the memory limit is 40MB but not when it's 64 or 128?

Comment: Yea, its really hard to say. Usually you would see a "memory limit exceeded (trying to put X bytes into memory on File:line)" or something similar.  I'm guessing since it is an AJAX plugin, it is trying to receive a file and running out of memory it just can't retrieve the whole file (and then when parsing the incomplete file it sees the SyntaxError)?  Totally shots in the dark though..

Comment: Yeah that's sort of my thinking too. If it was a syntax error then it's usually prone to breaking the entire site. I can literally increment the memory limit from 42-43MB, first one gives the error Unexpected Token and the second one works perfectly well.

Comment: And I should add, at 42MB memory the Admin panel has a fatal error too, Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 44040192 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes), and what does 44040192 bytes equal? 42MB EXACTLY.

Comment: Interesting..I usually don't like just falling back to a memory increase without *knowing* what is happening, but it seems like that is what you'll have to do. I'm assuming it has something to do with the AJAX.

Comment: That error message should always equal ***exactly*** what your memory limit is, since that is how many bytes they were able to use.  The allocating number is how many additional bytes PHP was trying to use when it failed.

Comment: No I agree, I don't like just increasing memory either without finding the problem, I just find it so strange that memory increase would fix a 'syntax' error unless like you say, it's parsing an incomplete file. And how come it exhausts the memory limit if it's allocating 30720 bytes and the limit is 44040192?

Comment: Yea I'm definitely baffled on the SyntaxError.  As far as the memory size exhausted error, this used to always confuse me.  Every line PHP executes has the change to allocate memory (saving variables, looping variables, initializing classes, calling methods, etc.). The function PHP ***failed*** on (it should give you a File:Line) was attempting had to allocate `30,720 bytes` but failed because it reached the `42MB` limit. If you change the limit to `43MB` or `41MB`, you should see it fail on a different line attempting to allocate a different amount of bytes.

Comment: Also, I deactivate some plugins, then the syntax error no longer happens at 41MB. Like it has enough memory now, so it doesn't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know we've been going back and forth in the comments with some discussion, but thought I'd post an answer since that `SyntaxError` was really bugging me (I knew it had something to do with AJAX) so I did some quick Google searches.

Yes all the plugins, how many posts you have, etc. will pile up and increase the amount of memory WordPress uses (I wouldn't be concerned unless you need to go above `256MB`). The reason the AJAX login was failing with a syntax error is because it was expecting to parse a JSON object (i.e. `{"success":false,"error":"User does not exist."}`) when in reality it was probably receiving something similar to (since most default Apache configurations have full HTML pages for their standard error messages):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 44040192 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes).
  </body>
</html>
```

When trying to parse this as JSON, it obviously failed with a `SyntaxError` when it hit the first `<`.  Anyways, I don't see it as a problem to raise your memory limit to `64MB` or `126MB`..

Comment: Thanks, Sam, I enjoy that mysterious syntax errors annoy you as much as they do me. I've been doing quite a bit of reading on memory limits and what's considered 'reasonable', with about 256MB being the upper limit. Would I be right to assume that if that was per/user on your site then with 8GM RAM you'd fast run into people getting syntax errors since all the memory on the server would be exhausted after you had more than about 40 users online? Or does it not work that way? I get worried if something is using more than 40MB of memory.

Comment: + I've had people tell me the issue happens sporadically when I've had the memory limit at 128MB, very strange indeed.

Comment: I think that is technically true in a sense, but you literally would need 40 concurrent requests (not to downplay your site, but I'd be surprised if your Apache server has yet to handle 3 simultaneous requests). As soon as a request is processed and a page is returned, the RAM is freed up for another request.  You should be able to set a max number of connections in your Apache server to avoid this.  And yea, different pages will take different amounts of memory (retrieving, storing, looping through, and parsing 10 blog posts will take a lot more than a static login page).

Comment: Is there a way to verify that syntax error and check that it is indeed a fatal error because it's returning that HTML page?

Comment: Take a look at the network requests using Chrome's inspector or Firefox's Firebug.  This should let you see every HTML, CSS, JS, image, AJAX, etc. request. If you catch the AJAX call, you can open it up and see the response contents (should be an HTML page saying memory limit exceeded).  If you don't follow, I can take a look if you give me a URL (and give you a screenshot).

Comment: Ah yes, you'r absolutely frickin' right! I was looking at chromes network tools earlier but I never looked at the response (idiot moment), only the headers.
It is indeed the memory.

`<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in <b>/home/somedoma/public_html/feedhumor.com/wp-admin/includes/post.php</b> on line <b>822</b><br />`

Comment: Glad you were able to get to the bottom of it :)

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it for me! :) So you think just increase the memory limit and drink a beer?

Comment: Haha, I think that's what I would do..definitely keep an eye on your plugins and stuff and don't just keep increasing the memory limit.  Also [`MaxClients`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1425182/703229) was what I was referring to before as far as the Apache setting for concurrent requests. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, appreciate it.