# php memory error message

Tags: mysql, linux, codeigniter, php-5.2

**Background Information**

We have a web interface (built using CI) that reports on data in a mysql database built by a third party.  This database is massive. 
For one particular report, we are getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 32 bytes) in
>   /var/www/localhost/htdocs/myapp/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php
>   on line 152

We've already increased the memory limit once in php.ini.  Before I do that again, I found this article:

[Increasing PHP memory_limit. At what point does it become insane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425138/increasing-php-memory-limit-at-what-point-does-it-become-insane)

I like the approach the user is suggesting the selected answer.  But I'm not exactly sure how to make practical application in my case.

The interface I've built is called like so:

```
http://internal_server/myreportingapplication/index.php/reporter/report_all_widgets
```

Another web app makes the curl call and consumes the json results for display. 
Although we have a lot of RAM on our server, I would like to try the 'php -d' option but I'm not sure how I would go about that in my case.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT 1**

In case this helps clarify the question...

In the link I refer to in my original question, the answer suggests doing the following:

> Instead, I would launch that job from command-line (or via a cron
>   job), and specify a higher memory_limit specificaly in this one and
>   only case.
>
> This can be done with the -d option of php, like :
>
> $ php -d memory_limit=1GB temp.php string(3) "1GB"

In my case, would that mean running something like this:

```
$ php -d memory_limit=1GB <path to my CI model or controller php file>
```

Thanks.

Comment: your job is consuming 512meg. You options are either to increase the memory limit, or change the job so it has a lower memory requirement. There's basically nothing to discuss. You've got two options, and will have to choose one of them.

Comment: @Mark B, I have made a choice, I'm asking how to implement it.

Comment: the `-d` option? that's just overriding the .ini limit, and your linked question shows the exact format to use anyways.

Comment: @Marc B, maybe my question is not clear enough.  I will modify it.  Your comments are just repeating what's already in the link I provided.  If the link was clear to me, i wouldn't be asking more questions.