# Fetch large amount of data in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have developed a bulk sms sending software. The software send millions of sms per day. Now I want to make some report with millions of data. But it cant fetch all data. It fetch `27000` row or less. I apply the query with only 2 fields id and mobile number.

when I try with raw php code in my other application it works fine but laravel can not fetch all data. it show the memory size exhausted error.

In my `php.ini` memory limit is `128M`

Now I want to know what is the best way to fetch millions of data in laravel. Or should I implement any other technology.

Comment: How do you try to fetch all data?

Comment: Have you tried to dump the data into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the solutions from @sblawrie answer from [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2152#issuecomment-78336469) github threat.

```
$query = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John');  //Pretend this is a huge data set

$statement = $query->getConnection()->getPdo()->prepare($query->toSql());
$statement->execute($query->getBindings());

while ($record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Do whatever you want, one row at a time
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use chunk method.

```
User::chunk(200, function($users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

If you need to process a lot (thousands) of Eloquent records, using the chunk command will allow you to do without using all of your RAM.

Or

You can run composer update with no memory limit and you can do it in following way

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can experiment with increasing your memory limit using `ini_set()`:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

Keep increasing it until you can get the records you need.

However, it is important to bear in mind how doing this might affect your server's performance if you are doing this regularly. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1425182/3865359) stackoverflow answer for more info on working out what is safe for your use case.

If your server does not have enough memory to retrieve all of the records that you want to at once, you will have to take the records in batches. This can be achieved either using the `take()` and `offset()` eloquent method.

Using the `take` and `offset` method:

```
Model::take(1000)->offset(1001)->get();
```

This will retrieve 1000 records beginning at the 1001st query result.