# Wordpress Error reconnecting to the database or out of memory

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have checked all posts regarding these here but still cannot find a solution. I can connect to my website only 1/3 of the time. Sometimes I got the error "Out of memory". I have change the php.ini and wp-config file, restart the server and it works now. After few minutes I reload the page and try again and now I got another problem "Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away" Error reconnecting to the database. I have already changed wp-config from localhost to  127.0.0.1 and still not working.

I am close to delete all files and delete wp / php / mysql / apache and re-install everything.

Any idea of my problem?

my php.ini:

max_input_vars = 3000
memory_limit = 64M

Comment: `I have change the php.ini and wp-config file,` How big is your DB, there is a separate `my.cnf` file for the DB.  If the DB is running out of memory, you may have to increase or tweek some of the settings, but it's not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: There are many reasons for this `Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away` if your using wordpress built in DB stuff, it should manage the connections pretty well, but if you have a lot of traffic you can run out of connections to the DB.  Or if you have a small server PHP can run out of memory.  I have a server with 64GB of ram (and like 24 cores), and I had to up the max connections due to excess trafic... :-p

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix DB is actually pretty small

Comment: I deal in the hundred thousands and even > 10 million rows.  This is really small `memory_limit = 64M`  I would make that at least `128M` or `256M`.  I have one script that runs up to `3GB for PHP` (on the command line), but it handles a huge amount of data (maybe 64GB of database data)...  But I have a pretty big server on AZURE its a  `D16 v3, 16 2.4 GHz Intel Xeon processors and 64GB ram`

Comment: Here is some information you may find helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425138/increasing-php-memory-limit-at-what-point-does-it-become-insane

Comment: One last question, is this a site wide issue, or does this happen only on a particular page or piece of code.  You can increase only the memory for a given script.

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix . I have just hundreds of rows in my database. I changed the memory_limit to 256M. My server is quite small actually. 1GB of ram CentOS  7.2. I have checked your link but not sure how to change my own data (memory_limit)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it is a site wide issue, happens to all pages. I run wordpress on it and admin and homepage are all down

Comment: `My server is quite small actually. 1GB of ram CentOS 7.2`  I would suggest getting a better server.  Wordpress and some plugins (that are not optimized well) will require more resources even on a small site.  Things like the Key Value type of model that wordpress uses causes a lot of DB calls, that is the price of flexibility for the DB schema.

Comment: For exampe wordpress uses a lot of meta data, this is stored as a KEY and a VALUE in the DB.  So if there is a lot of meta data each one can cause it's own DB lookup.  But without it, how would WordPress know how to store data for plugins that have not been written.  They would have no idea how to setup the DB for a plugin, so plugins would need to add many tables to the DB (some do) but for simple plugins you would wind up with a lot of various ways to do the same thing with no standards. But it's at the cost of performance.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Ok， what would you recommend as min of RAM？

Comment: probably 2GB for a small site, go up in small increments after playing with the PHP settings.  IF you are afraid of experimenting with the settings, make a backup of the current file   (copy and rename it) that way you know you can swap back to a known good config in a few seconds.  That way you can find what will work for your site, it's hard to estimate these things with so little info and I don't want to give you bad advice.